# Right Click on DataGrid always returns RowIndex -1

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

I have a WinForms application with datagrids in several places.

On one of the datagrids I have set up an event for a Right Click as follows:

```
private void dataBundles_CellMouseDown(object sender, DataGridViewCellMouseEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        if (e.Button == MouseButtons.Right)
        {
            var cell = dataBundles.HitTest(e.X, e.Y);
            int cellRow = cell.RowIndex;
            DataTable table = (DataTable)dataBundles.DataSource;
            string bundleID = table.Rows[cellRow]["BundleID"].ToString();
            dataBundles.Rows[cellRow].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.Red;
            if (MessageBox.Show("Are you sure you want to delete Bundle ID '" + bundleID + "'?",
                                "Confirm Delete Bundle", MessageBoxButtons.YesNo) == DialogResult.Yes)
            {
                int intBundleID = Int32.Parse(bundleID);
                cBundle bundle = new cBundle(intBundleID);
                bundle.Delete();
                PopulateDocumentsTab();                        
            }
            else
            {
                dataBundles.Rows[cellRow].DefaultCellStyle.BackColor = Color.White;
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception eX)
    {
        string eM = "Error occurred when right clicking the Bundles datagrid";
        aError err = new aError(eX, eM);
        MessageBox.Show(eX.Message, eM);
    }
}
```

However for some reason, no matter where I right click on this datagrid, the rowindex always returns a -1 which of course is 'off' the grid and so results in an error.

I can't see what I have done wrong as I have used identical code for right click events on other datagrids within the same application and they all work fine.

I'm sure whatever I am missing it is going to be something simple, but I've been starring at this code for a good while now.

Can someone put me out of my misery?

Comment: I had the same problem once, I didn't solve it, but discovered that I'd usually get 2 calls to my callback function. The first one was with row index = -1, and the second was valid. I solved it with a simple If statement. Did you check if receive multiple calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue at last . . .

I was using the 'CellMouseDown' event

once I transferred the same code to the 'MouseDown' event instead it worked

Comment: Was just about to post this myself. I have no idea why cellmousedown is behaving as you are seeing - one thing though, you don't actually need the hittest in the cellmousedown handler- the event args already have the row index. But anyway, as you found, mousedown is much more stable and the usual place to put code like you have.

Answer (score 0):

just some add code to avoid this error

```
if (cellRow == -1) return
```

the reason of this error its because you're using the `HitTest(e.X, e.Y)` for dataTable or `DataGridView` and you're trying to click somewhere in the DataGridView but not in the `Cell`, `Row` so it means the result is

> cellRow -1